# NASM: nested labels with more than one level

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to make something like this:

```
.lab1:
    ; ...
    .lab2:
        ; ...
        jmp ..lab3  ; -\
        ; ...  ;       |
        ..lab3:  ; <---/
        ; ...
    .lab3:  ; <----\
    ; ...  ;       |
    jmp .lab3  ; -/
```

I tried two dots but it's not working and creates error. Also I tried one dot but it says that label redefined.

Comment: NASM's `parent.local` nesting scheme doesn't support multiple levels of nesting.  NASM sees `.lab2:` as `foo.lab2` where `foo:` was the last non-dot label.  You're going to have to come up with more meaningful and unique names, or do something entirely different (like auto-numbered labels in a macro or something.)

Comment: My NASM macro collection contains an implementation of anonymous local labels: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/e611130fc291/lmacros2.mac#l995 You place a label as `@@:` and refer to it using eg `jmp @B` (prior @@) or `jmp @F` (next @@). This is not what you asked for but does provide another way to use local labels.